# Setting a Struts2 select tag to a variable from the request object

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, ognl, valuestack

I want to set the Struts2 `select` tag to a variable from the `request` object instead of the action class variable.

**My action class is:**

```
     public class showSchdulesAction extends ActionSupport     
         public String execute() throws Exception {
               ...
            HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
           request.setAttribute("repTypList",someObj.getCommonList());
              ...
          }
      }
```

**My JSP page:**

```
...
<s:select  onchange="genRpt(this)" list="%{repTypList}" listKey="id" listValue="val" >

</s:select>
...
```

I want to set the `repTypeList` from the request object to `select` tag.
When I used `list="%{repTypList}"` or `list="repTypList"` then

**I got error:**

```
tag 'select', field 'list': The requested list key '%{repTypList}' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name}
```

When I use `list="#{repTypList}"` it's working but no value is shown in the combo options, even values in list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reason to get an object from the request in Struts2. If you are using Struts2 tag you can get the object from the `valueStack` via OGNL. However in Struts2 is possible to get the value from the request attributes using OGNL. For this purpose you should access the OGNL context variable `request`. For example

```
<s:select  list="%{#request.repTypList}" listKey="id" listValue="val" />
```

The `select` tag requires not `null` value returned via OGNL expression in the `list` tag, as a result of `null` value you got the error. So, better to check this in the action before the result is returned.

```
 public class showSchdulesAction extends ActionSupport     
     public String execute() throws Exception {
           ...
        HttpServletRequest request = ServletActionContext.getRequest();
        List list = someObj.getCommonList();
        if (list == null) list = new ArrayList(); 
        request.setAttribute("repTypList", list);
          ...
      }
  }
```

This code will save you from the error above.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this..

```
list="%{#repTypList}"
```

**OR**

```
list="%{#request.repTypList}"
```

in struts 2 select tag

Comment: list="%{#request.REP_TYP_LIST}" this one worked 
thanks Prakash.